# C# call function from outside current class

Tags: c#, function, invoke

Currently have a mainForm.cs which calls a class panel.cs

panel.cs holds multiple pictureboxes with events such as _click, _mousedown, _mouseup

I wish to call a function in mainForm.cs from panel.cs

do i need to use a callback / delegate. Is there another way to access this function

I have tried
Main main = new Main();
main.functioninMain does not work

any help or direction would be appreciated.

for example

```
panel.cs
  private void pb_button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(main.functioninMain));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not instantiate another object of MainForm, which creates a duplicate and all the objects withing the new MainForm will not have the values of your actual MainForm.

**Approach 1**
You can try creating a static instance of you MainForm like below

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public static MainForm Instance = null;
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Instance = this;
    }
    public SomeMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

Now if you have your panel class, then you can easily access public methods and variables of MainClass

```
class Panel : Form
{
    public Panel()
    {
        MainForm.Instance.SomeMethod();
    }

}
```

**Edit: Pass Handle as parameter to the form**  (From Ben Voigt's suggestion)

**Approach 2:**

As Ben suggested, it is also important to have a safer code, so much cleaner approach will be passing handle of the control as parameter and then to access them.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TestClass test = new TestClass();
        test.ModifyText(textBox1);
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public void ModifyText(TextBox textBox)
    {
        textBox.Text = "New text";
    }
}
```

Comment: This probably will work for the main window, since there should only be one, but a cleaner approach is to pass a handle to the parent when the panel is created.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes I agree to you suggestion and hence updated the answer with an approach for passing handle of controls to handle them.

Comment: @justin89 Please also see the second approach and accept the answer if it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

If we can use delegate & events something like this

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel formPanel = new Panel();
        formPanel.OnPanelClick += new Panel.OnPanelButtonClick(formPanel_OnPanelClick);
        formPanel.Show();
    }

    void formPanel_OnPanelClick(string a)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(a);
    }
}

public partial class Panel : Form
{
    public delegate void OnPanelButtonClick(string a);
    public event OnPanelButtonClick OnPanelClick = null;

    public Panel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (OnPanelClick != null)
        {
            OnPanelClick("from Panel.cs");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid circular dependencies at all costs (class A depends on class B, and class B depends on Class A).

There are so many ways to do this, but perhaps one of the easier ways is to use an interface. mainForm.cs implements it like this:

```
public class mainForm : IMainForm {
  // This method is defined in the interface, so mainForm
  // must implement it.
  public string GetStringFromMainForm() {
    return "Hello from MainForm";
  }

  public void CreatePanel() {
    // pass in a reference to myself so panel knows how to
    // talk to me.
    var panel = new Panel(this);
  }
}
```

And IMainForm (the interface) could look like this:

```
public interface IMainForm {
  string GetStringFromMainForm();
}
```

Then your panel class can talk to the Main form without having to reference mainForm.cs explicitly:

```
public class Panel {
  // use a private variable to keep track of main form
  private IMainForm _mainForm;

  // Constructor: pass in a class that implements IMainForm. It isn't
  // a type of MainForm, so there's no dependency on the concrete class.
  public Panel(IMainForm mainForm) {
    _mainForm = mainForm;
  }

  public void TalkToMainForm() {
    var resultFromMainForm = _mainForm.GetStringFromMainForm();
    Console.WriteLine(resultFromMainForm);
  }
}
```